# Let $(E; d)$ be a metric space and $M \subseteq E$. Show the following:

Tags: analysis

1)If $x \epsilon M$ then x is either a limit point of an isolated point of M.

2) If M is finite then M is closed.

Answer (score 1):

1) Either $$\forall \varepsilon>0, (M\backslash \{x\})\cap B(x,\varepsilon)\neq \emptyset,$$
or $$\exists \varepsilon>0: (M\backslash \{x\})\cap B(x,\varepsilon)=\emptyset.$$

In both cases, the claim follow.

2) If $M$ is finite, then $M$ is a finite union of singleton. In other word, there is $x_1,...,x_n$ s.t. $$M=\{x_1\}\cup...\cup \{x_n\}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I didnt understand your explanation for the 2nd part. Would it be possible to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @onknc: I edited my answer.